# How do I remove extra lists from output using Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm working on improving my coding skills, and have been doing so by creating functions that can solve math problems.

I'm trying to set up a simple equation: S = 1/n where n can be any integer > 0. I've set up the code so that the output shows me the list of the results.

```
def Sup(n):
    list = []
    for n in range (1,n+1):
        Sup = (1/n)
        list.append(Sup)
        print (list)
Sup(4)

[1.0]
[1.0, 0.5]
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25]
```

I've managed to do this however, I would like to get only one list showing what the result is for when n=1,2,3,4. The final list is what I want to only have, not the 3 lists before it. Why am I getting multiple lists?

Comment: you're printing inside the loop.

Comment: Don't use the same name for function and variable. It looks ugly and in the worst case, it would be buggy.

Comment: good point, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You the the printout of many lists because you have your `print` statement *inside* the loop. So each list gets printed. To get only the final list printed, out-dent the `print` statement so it is out of the loop.

```
def Sup(n):
    list = []
    for n in range (1,n+1):
        Sup = (1/n)
        list.append(Sup)
    print (list)  # out-dented!
Sup(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `print (list)` out of the loop:

```
def Sup(n):
    list = []
    for n in range (1,n+1):
        Sup = (1/n)
        list.append(Sup)
    print (list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the last print statement out of the loop. Right now it's printed with the loop for each iteration, but if you want it to only print once, remove the indentation so it will only print after the loop is finised:

```
def Sup(n):
    list = []
    for n in range (1,n+1):
        Sup = (1/n)
        list.append(Sup)
    # Move this print statement down
    print (list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `print()` *inside* of the `for` loop, leading to `print()` being called on every iteration. You're encountering an issue of scope, if you want to google for more details. If you unindent the call to `print()` by one level, it will be in the function scope instead of the loop scope, and will only be called once the looping is completed.